# Using template metaprogramming to wrap C-style variadic arguments

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, metaprogramming

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ DLL that exports a function that accepts a variadic parameter like this:

```
__declspec( dllexport ) void DLL_Foo( int count, ... )
{
    va_list list;
    va_start( list, count );

    for( ; count; --count )
    {
        const wchar_t* item = va_arg( list, const wchar_t* );
        if( count % 2 == 0 )
            printfW( L"[%s] ", item );
        else
            printfW( L"%s ", item );
    }

    va_end( list );

    printfW( L"\r\n" );
}
```

The expected usage is something like this:

```
DLL_Foo( 4, L"int", L"1", L"const wchar_t*", L"Hello" );
```

Where the output would be:

```
[int] 1, [const wchar_t*] Hello
```

To simplify the usage of this function, I intend to include a C++ template function like this:

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
void Foo( T1 p1, T2 p2 )
{
    std::wstringstream t1W;
    t1W << typeid( p1 ).name();
    std::wstringstream p1W;
    p1W << p1;

    std::wstringstream t2W;
    t2W << typeid( p2 ).name();
    std::wstringstream p2W;
    p2W << p2;

    ::DLL_Foo( 4, t1W.str().c_str(), p1W.str().c_str(), t2W.str().c_str(), p2W.str().c_str() );
};
```

Where the expected usage is like this:

```
int a = 1;
const wchar_t* b = L"Hello";
Foo( a, b );
```

With the same expected output as before.

Is there a template recursion method I can employ so that I don't have to implement a different `template<> Foo()` function for 0..n parameters?

```
template<> void Foo();
template< class T1 > void Foo( T1 p1 );
template< class T1, ..., class N > void Foo( T1 p1, ..., N n );
```

Please, no solutions involving variadic templates or other C++0x features. I realize they're wonderful, but I'm using VS2008. Also, just to be more difficult, I cannot make use of boost functionality like boost::MPL.

Thanks,
PaulH

---

**Edit:** Yes, the DLL actual dll function does more than print the type and value information. The actual DLL function looks a bit more like this:

```
__declspec( dllexport ) void DLL_Foo( MYHANDLE handle, int count, ... )
{
    CMyObject* obj = reinterpret_cast< CMyObject* >( handle );

    va_list list;
    for( va_start( list, count ); count; --count )
    {
        const wchar_t* item = va_arg( list, const wchar_t* );
        if( count % 2 == 0 )
        {
            obj->AddTypeInfo( item );
        }
        else
        {
            obj->AddValueInfo( item );
        }
    }

    va_end( list );
}
```

Comment: If that's the source of the function, why not just junk it and put the functionality in Foo() yourself? Half the function is just variable arguments handling.

Comment: @DeadMG - That's not the complete function. DLL_Foo() will process the information and use to to alter the state of an object that is passed in as a handle, then return it as a handle. If that isn't at odds with your suggestion, can you elaborate more on what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible using C++0x features. If you cannot use its variadic templates, you cannot create a function … uh, that takes a variable number of templates.

On the other hand, you *can* create multiple overloads of the same method, each with its own number of arguments (1 … some upper limit). That’s of course quite a bit of work.

Comment: Not quite. If he had access to Boost.PP and Boost.MPL he could do it too. Technically you could just look at how Boost.MPL implements `vector` and code your own. You basically would have to re-implement parts of MPL and PP yourself.

Comment: It doesn't have to be truly variadic. A fixed upper limit solution is acceptable. 0..6 parameters, for example should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Konrad's answer is right.

However, you could avoid writing the multiple overloads at the cost of a slight inconvenience for your users by having `Foo` accept a tuple, something like:

```
template<class TupleT>
void Foo(const TupleT& Args)
```

And ask the caller to wrap the arguments in a tuple when calling Foo:

```
//Foo(an_int, a_bool, a_whatever);
Foo(boost::make_tuple(an_int, a_bool, a_whatever));
```

... and now, right as I am about to click the "Post Your Answer" button, I see that you can't use Boost. Can you use the feature pack? I think it has std::tr1::tuple.

Comment: @Éric - std::TR1 doesn't appear to be in our SDK. To clarify, I can use the standard library and the windows SDK and C++ language features available to the VS2008 compiler. I believe boost will compile and run. I just can't use it (yes, I hate this limitation, too). So, I will likely need to implement some small part of the voodo that is boost.MPL to get this done. I just don't know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I needed to do something like this I wrote a perl script that would generate the templates for me.

Downside is you end up with a lot of code to compile, but it depends on what your max is.